# Replicating a website's mobile appearance in an iframe

Tags: javascript, android, html, iframe, word-wrap

(First time doing this, so I hope I'm doing it right)

As a part of a bigger project, I'm interested in being able to show an iframe with the contents of another site as it would look if viewed on a mobile device. I understand that I might run into some issues later on with mobile-specific looks and such but with my current tests I'm using a simple site with no special mobile design.

So I started out with visiting the site on my mobile phone (Galaxy S3). Here's a picture I took as reference of what it looks like on it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUJpZ.png

The important thing to notice is where the text wraps. The first row is "Turtles are reptiles of the order Chelonii[2]"

Now, if I were to visit it on my computer, the first row would be longer: "Turtles are reptiles of the order Chelonii[2] or Testudines characterised by a special bony or "

If I were to just resize the iframe, it wont automatically resize the paragraphs and such, making them wrap earlier.

I decided to google it and see if I could find a site doing the same thing. However, each one I tried displayed it wrong. All of them have the longer version as the first row. Here's some of the ones I tried:

1. iPhone tester
2. Mobile Phone Emulator
3. Responsivepx
4. Screenfly

Here's an album showing the results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kuYi.jpg

As you can see, most of them look almost the same, but none of them looks or wraps like my mobile phone. This is despite me telling these sites to use a Galaxy S3 preset if available.

To clarify, I am not interested in finding another site that does this (except as a proof of concept). I want to know how to detect things like where the text wraps and the font size so that I can replicate it in an iframe.

If I've left out any vital information, tell me and I'll add it.

Comment: did you try chrome's dev tools's built-in emulation feature? it works pretty well for CSS.

Comment: I didn't know about that. Unfortunately, it seems to give the same result as the other emulation sites I tried.